# Backbone: Render function fires for each instance of model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have 4 instances of a model. Why is the render function firing four times? I would like it to only render once (and loop through each model and fire off a handlebars template). On the front-end, if I have four instances of the model, I'm getting 16 templates. Apologies if I'm describing this with the wrong nomenclature. I'm a noob.

```
define(['handlebars', 'text!event-template'],
    function(Handlebars, EventTemplate) {

        var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#event-list')[0],

            initialize: function(collection) {
                this.collection = collection;
                this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
                console.log('View Event : Initialized');
            },

            render : function() {
                var _el = this.$el; //refrencing the el: above

                _.each(this.collection.models, function(model) {
                    var template = Handlebars.default.compile($(EventTemplate).html());
                    _el.append(template(model.attributes));
                });
                console.log('rendering');
            }
        });
        return EventView;
    }
);
```

Comment: Why not say `el: '#event-list'` and let Backbone deal with it for you? Also, you can say `this.collection.each(function(model) { ... }, this)` to avoid accessing the collection's `models` directly and get the right `this` inside the the callback. You should also use `mode.toJSON()` instead of `model.attributes` to avoid accidentally altering the model's attributes behind its back. Might as well move the `Handlebars.default.compile` call outside the `_.each` too, that way you only do that bit of work once.

Comment: Traditionally, `initialize` gets an `options` object as its argument, if one of those options is called `collection` then Backbone will set the view's `this.collection` for you.

Comment: I agree with you @muistooshort that there could be some good amount refactoring that can be done that basically just needs more experience in knowing more of the Backbone/underscore capabilities. But in terms of the handlebars compile, maybe he really wants to bind to this "add" event which has some nice effects when you just want to add models on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a collection is sync'ed it fires an `add` for each model added to the collection.  If you want to bind to the `add`, what I usually do is make a method called "append" to add a single model to the view. The `add` event will iterate through the collection, so you won't need a "loop" on the view which keeps it clean and more of a One-to-One relationship between adding into a collection and adding to the view. So I would change your code to this

```
define(['handlebars', 'text!event-template'],
    function(Handlebars, EventTemplate) {

        var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#event-list')[0],

            initialize: function(collection) {
                this.collection = collection;
                this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.append);
                console.log('View Event : Initialized');
            },

            append: function( model ) {
                var _el = this.$el; //refrencing the el: above
                var template = Handlebars.default.compile($(EventTemplate).html());
                _el.append(template(model.attributes));

                console.log('adding');
            }
        });
        return EventView;
    }
);
```

This is a nice implementation.  After this, if you "add" a model to the collection, automatically, it'll will show up in the DOM right away.

Comment: When I changed this to 'reset' the render function no longer fires? I'm a missing a line to cause the collection to reset?

Comment: Ok so you're not sync'ing the collection the to the view.  Let me change my answer for you

Comment: Thanks for the code and more importantly explaining what was happening behind the scenes!

Comment: You're welcome (please vote me up. teehee =).  Also, if you really want to see behind the scenes in all the events of a particular Backbone class, do this:  `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', console.log);`.  SUPER helpful! =)